# SQL Server 2008, Server side trace disappears

Tags: sql-server, profiler, trace, sql-server-2008-r2

What would cause a server side trace to disappear before I call exec sp_trace_setstatus @TraceID, 2?

On a local database, I'm using SQL profiler to export a server side trace definition. 
I'm setting the filename and running the generated script and the trace shows up as expected in

```
SELECT * FROM ::fn_trace_getinfo(default)
```

However, before my test harness finishes, fn_get_traceinfo shows the trace has disappeared and the trace file saved only matches the 1st half of the database workload.
No errors are being thrown and I get the same results no matter what trace template I use. @@version is `Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64)   Apr  2 2010 15:48:46   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7600: )`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the event log I found

```
Trace ID '2' was stopped because of an error. Cause: Stopping the trace because the current trace file is full and the rollover option is not specified.. Restart the trace after correcting the problem.
```

At the top of the trace definition is a @maxfilesize variable, bump htat and problem solved.

Comment: You can indeed increase the @maxfilesize but this will not fix this problem. It will eventually happen again when the max file size threshold is exceeded. To fix this problem, you should use the rollover option when creating your trace: `EXEC sp_trace_create @your_trace_id output, 2, @file_name, @max_file_size, NULL`. The integer 2 is the `TRACE_FILE_ROLLOVER` option. More details in the official doc at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-trace-create-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments.